# displaying results from mysql with php foreach.... very confused

Tags: php

Hi I'm getting confused as to how to display results with foreach loops. It seems there are slight differences depending on the structure of the array? ie if its a simple array, associative or multi-dimensional? I have looked at other answers for this site but I am still very much confused.

i have connected to mysql db with this code

```
try
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', '*****',
'*****');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.' . $e->getMessage;
echo $error;
exit();
}
```

//next i want to retrieve the 'id' and 'name' from a db table...

```
$results = $pdo->query('select id, name FROM author');
```

//now I want to display those results on the page... i tried a foreach loop...

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
echo $result;
}
```

//but this just displays error message...

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$results' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Connect\admin\authors\test.php on line 6

Please help as im very confused. I just want to know how to display results from a db query like this with a foreach, and what rules apply when displaying different kinds of results from such queries.

I think it involves writing a foreach something like this ....

```
foreach ($results as $result=> $item) {
echo $item;
}
```

but i dont undertsand this either.

Any simplified approach to this would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for some time.

Thanks Rob.

Comment: could you show me `var_dump($results);`

Comment: $results = $pdo->query('select id, name FROM author'); should be "SELECT id, name FROM author ", note upper case

Comment: @dwhite.me : What's wrong with them? problem is capitalize?

Comment: @dwhite.me Your suggestion as a joke was very funny, you made me laugh, thank you for this! ... er well this was a joke, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result` is an `array` not the `string`.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM author");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result['id'];
    echo $result['name'];
}
```

or print the `array` like this,

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: Hi Ranjith, thanks for your help. This is the var-dump you asked for...  object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(27) "select id, name FROM author" }

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with prepared statements, I always do even if I am not injecting parameters, keeps things a bit clearer.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select id, name FROM author');
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

You can use the statement `fetch` method, and with the constant `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to ensure each row is an associative array.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didnt realise i would get responses so quickly. I will try all these suggestions and let you know of my progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to SELECT something from a database, below is the general format of what you'll need:

```
try {
    //First, you initialise a connection to the database (in this case I'm using *constants*).
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

    //Secondly, we'll prepare our query - SELECT the id and name FROM table author
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM author");

    // Then we must execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // After execution, we must perform some function to get the results
    // This function fetches ALL the results as an array so we can loop 
    // through them with foreach. 
    // (Other methods include a while loop and "fetch()" for one row at a time)
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();


    // Then we just loop through everything
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['name'];
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```